# Undefined error when trying to include .eps

Tags: graphics, pdftex, miktex, eps, epstopdf

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics*[50pt,500pt][400pt,750pt]{figs/ch3/pda_anbn.eps}
\end{document}
```

---

```
Error says the \includegraphics line is undefined. I'm using Miktex 2.9.

Specifically the error message is "! Undefined control sequence.<argument> ...onverted-to.pdf image\GPT@AttrShort\ifx \GPT@print \ltx@empty... ...500pt][400pt,750pt]{figs/ch3/pda_anbn.eps}".
```

Note: I see the pdf is being generated, in the same folder, from the eps. So epstopdf is working. Could it be something wrong with the includegraphics syntax?

Comment: I removed the two optional arguments, then there were no errors. Can someone suggest a way to make it work with the args?

Comment: Well, `\includegraphics` can't take that many arguments. Or arguments in that form. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @cfr,I'm pretty sure `\includegraphics` can. See [graphics](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphics). I have this original doc that uses that syntax and it works. I'm converting it to use the `epstopdf` and `graphicx` packages. `graphicx` manual says it should be backwards compatible with that syntax, but that could be wrong.

Comment: Can you give me a page number? The manual says that package authors should avoid `graphicx` because it would commit users to the key-value interface. That strongly suggests that you cannot use the two optional arguments if you load `graphicx`. See pages 15-16. EDIT: But that seems to contradict the claim on page 10.

Comment: It doesn't work if you load `graphics` either. Bug, maybe?

Comment: It works if you use LaTeX rather than pdfLaTeX and go the `.dvi` -> route rather than generating `.pdf` directly.

Comment: p9-10, section 4.4

"Also, for increased
compatibility, if two optional arguments are used, the ‘standard’ version of
\includegraphics is always used, even if the graphicx package is loaded.)"

I'm actually having problems with the two arguments with the `graphics`. (this is contradicting what I might've previously said). Yes, I've tried the latex route before, and that does work. Currently, I think I'll just convert all the two arguments into the key-value, one argument; that is working for what I want.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the pdftex driver as it doesn't even work with `graphics`. So you should contact @HeikoOberdiek. On the other side: It doesn't make much sense to load `graphicx` and not to use its syntax and its extended capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdfTeX consists of TeX and the driver part, which produces PDF. Therefore it is able to detect the bounding/media boxes of the included image files. A manual specifying of the bounding box does not make much sense:

- The user would have to determine the bounding box values. What's the bounding box of a PNG file? What is the bounding box of the fifth page of a ten page PDF file?
- What's the bounding box, if the image file was given without extension and there are several choices with different internal bounding boxes?
- What happens, if the image file changes. Who updates the bounding box data
  in the TeX file?
- How to deal with rounding errors?
- What is the interpretation of a user "lie", if the specified bounding box differs from the actual bounding box?

Therefore the driver `pdftex.def` does not support the manual specification of the bounding box, because it is not needed. If the user wants to have a portion of the image, there are options `viewport` and `trim` to specify this wish in a cleaner way. Option `bb` is treated as `viewport` with a warning.

Nevertheless the actual error of the two optional argument form of `\includegraphics` is a bug. A fix will have to replace it by a better
error message or by a similar behavior as option `bb`. (I have not yet analyzed
the internals.)